# Xamarin MacOS CGDisplayStream bindings

Tags: xamarin, core-graphics, xamarin.mac

I'd like to use [CGDisplayStream](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgdisplaystream) API using Xamarin for MacOS, however it seems that there are no bindings for it yet.

I browsed the code in https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/tree/main/src/CoreGraphics and didn't find any references to CGDisplayStream, the only place where I could find trace about this type was Wiki on Bindings: [1](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/wiki/CoreGraphics-macOS-xcode9-beta1), [2](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/wiki/CoreGraphics-macOS-xcode11-beta1), [3](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/wiki/CoreGraphics-macOS-xcode12-GM), but I'm not really sure how to read these pages.

1. Are these bindings currently missing?
2. If so, is that because there was no prior demand to incorporate those APIs, or is there something special about CGDisplayStream that makes it hard to bring into Xamarin?
3. If it's just about lack of demand, could someone guide me on how to potentially contribute adding such bindings?

Comment: You should post a github issue regarding the missing binding to get an "official" answer. There are a bunch of macOS specific binding missing from Xamarin.Mac, the answer is usually lack of demand as macOS is a VERY small development target for MSFT/Xamarin. Things like Xamarin not handling  `@dynamic property`, etc... is not unusual and you either do it yourself or use a different dev platform

Comment: i.e.  I added ObjC `@dynamic` support so CoreAnimation/CALayer properties can be animated on iOS/macOS via Xamarin..., Xamarin's devs were impressed I did it, and they added to the future ench. list, but that was 3+ years ago and it is still not a supported feature.

Comment: Thanks @SushiHangover I initially wanted to submit GH issue, but then stumbled upon https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/wiki/Submitting-Bugs-&-Suggestions#before-submitting-an-issue "If your issue is a question then please ask the question on Stack Overflow using the tag xamarin.ios or on the Xamarin Forums (Xamarin.iOS | Xamarin.Mac)."

Comment: I would not consider a "question" about missing/non-bound APIs a generic question about development (that is what SO is for), I would definitely post an issue concerning it since it is a missing feature in the Xamarin.Mac distro

Comment: Posted the same question on Xamarin GitHub: https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/11712